# Efficiently generating fake data in R

Tags: r, performance

I have the following: 7 treatments, 6 locations, 4 replicates, and yield. I use the rep command to generate the pattern for treatment, location, and replicate. I now need to generate the yield data. One important part to this is that the plots can consist of 4, 8, or 12 plants (plotsize). The program starts by initializing an vector of 1,000,000 plants that will be sampled. I fill the yield variable using for loops.

```
for (i in 1:reps) y[i]<-mean(sample(vector,plotsize))
yield<-append(yield,y1)
for (i in 1:reps) y[i]<-mean(5+sample(vector,plotsize))
yield<-append(yield,y1)
for (i in 1:reps) y[i]<-mean(10+sample(vector,plotsize))
yield<-append(yield,y1)
```

The first pair of statements is for the control. Each treatment is 5 units greater than the last. Continuing this process gives an answer that works. I could rewrite the code as:

```
for (j in 1:7) {
    for (i in 1:reps) y[i]<-mean((j*5)+sample(vector,plotsize))
    yield<-append(yield,y1)
}
```

Is there an approach to getting the same result that executes faster?